# Delay in Website Loading in Page Insights

Tags: pagespeed, google-pagespeed, pagespeed-insights, core-web-vitals

Please check this Screenshot: [Page Insights Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMLqI.png)

I have marked in it. I have 2 Questions:

1. Why the website is loading after 4-5 Slides in the Page Insights.
2. Why the FID is not fetching in Page Insights.

Thanks

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [ask]

Answer (score 0):

1. Could be any number of reasons. A few slides of non-content are expected for most sites. The filmstrip is suppose to show *how* it loads (in your case the menu loads first, then the image), rather than how slowly it loads. The stats above are more important but they do show it being slow. Page speed insights will give plenty of advice and guidance on improving your performance below the filmstrip.
2. FID is a measure of how long it take from interaction (I.e. clicking on a button) until that interaction is processed. Many static, content, sites (e.g. newspapers, blogs and other articles) will not have an interaction (scrolling don’t count as interactions for FID for example) so it’s perfectly normal for there to be no FID score there. In this case FID is ignored in terms of whether you pass or fail Core Web Vitals so no FID is effectively the same as a passing FID.

Comment: Hi Barry,

Thanks for reply! Our website is E Commerce Shopping Website. It is alright if FID is not showing in page insights?